# what are the files exectuing in order when starting mysql?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-10.04

I want to debug where mysql starting is hanged up,so i need what are the files executing in order when starting mysql through service.

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `strace` and `lsof`?

Comment: I tried strace , its amazing. for simple cat its giving tons of information. But I think separate program is required to process output of strace.same for lsof. I am very new to this type of debugging. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try "set -x" at the scripts beginning, this will help to see where it hangs, use strace and lsof to see why that binary hangs.